# @Autowired dependency injection returns null pointer for static field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm working on a project in which I'm trying to inject dependency into a class but `@Autowired` annotating does not seem to work for some reason.

I have the class **ApplicationServer**

```
package project.eHealth;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import project.eHealth.bussiness.AppointmentDto;
import project.eHealth.bussiness.AppointmentService;

@SpringBootApplication
@Component
public class ApplicationServer {

    private static final int PORT = 9001;

    private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

    @Autowired
    private static AppointmentService appointments;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationServer.class, args);
        System.out.println("The chat server is running.");
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }

    }

        private static class Handler extends Thread {

            private String name;
            private Socket socket;
            private BufferedReader in;
            private PrintWriter out;




            /**
             * Constructs a handler thread, squirreling away the socket.
             * All the interesting work is done in the run method.
             */
            public Handler(Socket socket) {
                this.socket = socket;
            }

            /**
             * Services this thread's client by repeatedly requesting a
             * screen name until a unique one has been submitted, then
             * acknowledges the name and registers the output stream for
             * the client in a global set, then repeatedly gets inputs and
             * broadcasts them.
             */
            public void run() {


                try {

                    // Create character streams for the socket.
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


                    // Request a name from this client.  Keep requesting until
                    // a name is submitted that is not already used.  Note that
                    // checking for the existence of a name and adding the name
                    // must be done while locking the set of names.
                    /*while (true) {
                        out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                        name = in.readLine();
                        if (name == null) {
                            return;
                        }
                        synchronized (names) {
                            if (!names.contains(name)) {
                                names.add(name);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }*/

                    // Now that a successful name has been chosen, add the
                    // socket's print writer to the set of all writers so
                    // this client can receive broadcast messages.



                    // Accept messages from this client and broadcast them.
                    // Ignore other clients that cannot be broadcasted to.
                    while (true) {

                        System.out.println("Aici este controlul!");
                        String input = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println(input);

                        Request request = mapper.readValue(input,Request.class);

                        if (request.getCommand().equals("getAllAppointments")){

                        if (appointments == null){
                            System.out.println("appointmentService is null");
                        }
                        else{
                                List<AppointmentDto> appointmentsList = appointments.getAll();
                                Response response = new Response();
                                response.setAction("RETURNED");
                                response.setData(mapper.writeValueAsString(appointmentsList));
                                String respObj = mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
                                out.println(respObj);
                        }   


                        }

                        System.out.println(input);
                        if (input == null) {
                            return;
                        }

                       String[] command = input.split("&");

                       }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                } finally {
                    // This client is going down!  Remove its name and its print
                    // writer from the sets, and close its socket.
                    if (name != null) {

                    }
                    if (out != null) {

                    }

                }
            }




    }
    }
```

And the class **AppointmentService**

```
package project.serverSide.server.bussiness;



import java.time.LocalDate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import project.serverSide.server.data.Appointment;
import project.serverSide.server.data.AppointmentRepository;


@Component
@Service
public class AppointmentService {

    @Autowired
    AppointmentRepository appointments;

    public AppointmentService(){

    }

    public List<AppointmentDto> getAll(){

        List<Appointment> appointmentsList = appointments.findAll();
        List<AppointmentDto> appointmentsDto = new ArrayList<AppointmentDto>();

        for (Appointment ap : appointmentsList){
            AppointmentDto apDto = new AppointmentDto();
            apDto.setDoctorName(new SimpleStringProperty(ap.getDoctorName()));
            apDto.setPatientName(new SimpleStringProperty(ap.getPatientName()));
            apDto.setDateIssued(new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(ap.getDateIssued()));
            appointmentsDto.add(apDto);
        }

        return appointmentsDto;
    }
}
```

And **AppointmentRepository**

```
  package project.serverSide.server.data;


    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment,Integer> {
        List<Appointment> findAll();
    }
```

The issue is that **ApplicationServer** class does not inject the **AppointmentService** for some reason and I do not know why. I've been spending an important number of hours search for an answer but without any result.

Help is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing [@ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) in your `ApplicationServer` class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"project.serverSide"})
public class ApplicationServer {
}
```

And remove `static` from `AppointmentService`:

```
@Autowired
private AppointmentService appointments;
```

If you need static instance variable then use setter injection instead, as follows:

```
private static AppointmentService appointments;

@Autowired
public void setAppointments(AppointmentService appointments){
    ApplicationServer.appointments = appointments;
}
```

Comment: I have forgoten to mention that the application is succesfully launched (it does not throw an Exception at build time)

Answer (score -1):

you need to add base package in `ApplicationContext.xml`, u=you can use below code :-

```
<context:component-scan annotation-config="true"
    base-package="com.amstech.mayal" />
```

below code use for add base package fot repositories:-

```
<context:annotation-config />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.amstech.mayal.repository" />
```

and also add below code for Autowired:-

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```